# How to convert a Date to an Int in Haskell

Tags: date, haskell

I'm having a bit of a problem with converting the output of these functions below to an Int

```
date :: IO (Integer,Int,Int)
date = getCurrentTime >>= return . toGregorian . utctDay

date' :: IO Integer
date' = getCurrentTime >>= return . toModifiedJulianDay . utctDay
```

Basically I want to take the output from either (not fussed which as long as it's possible) and turn it into an int. e.g. Today is the 20/4/11 so `date` would give `(2011,4,20)` and `date'` would give `55671`.

In an ideal world I want a couple of functions to flatten these IO functions to give an Int – `(2011,4,20)` to `2011420` and `55671` (currently of type IO Integer) to `55671` as an Int

Please advise me if there are better ways of completing this!
edit: Sorry if it wasnt clear, I meant how can you convert the output of date `(2011,4,20) :: IO (Integer,Int,Int)` to `20110420 :: Int`

Comment: If you're trying to get a pure value out of an impure function (i.e. you want `date''` defined in terms of `date'` to return a plain `Integer`), you better drop whatever you're doing and go read a tutorial on that topic... even the worse ones usually manage to state the "seperation of IO and pure code" thing clearly enough.

Comment: Is your question how you can convert `(2011,4,20)` to `20110420`, or is it how to convert an `IO Integer` to a plain `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood part of your question correctly, you basically want a function, say `f`, such that `f (123,456,789) = 123456789`, where all those numbers are numbers. So `f :: (Integer, Int, Int) -> Integer`.

```
module Temp where

import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate

date :: UTCTime -> (Integer, Int, Int)
date = toWeekDate . utctDay

f :: (Integer, Int, Int) -> Integer
f (a,b,c) = read $ show a ++ show b ++ show c 

main = do
  utcTime <- getCurrentTime
  putStr "original format: " >>  print (date utcTime)
  putStr "flattened format: " >> print (f . date $ utcTime)
```

In ghci:

```
*Temp> main
original format: (2011,16,3)
flattened format: 2011163
```

edit: Please never forget, that basically, there is no (noncheating) function `IO a -> a`. So what you want is impossible unless you break purity principles. Please consider just using the function `fmap f :: IO (Integer, Int, Int) -> IO Integer`.

Comment: I am very confused! I know there are no functions such that `IO a -> a` which aren't considered bad practice. But I am still struggling to eliminate the IO element. In a perfect world I would have something that takes the `UTCTime -> (Integer, Int, Int)` of date and JUST return an `Int` as desribed. No `IO` involved at all. A pure `Int`. This is key to what I am doing.

Comment: @Ed George. Can you clearly say what function signature you're looking for? Is it `UTCTime -> Integer`? I could help you much easier if I knew what you're looking for. Also, as always ask yourself if such a type signature is *sensible*. And what it means described in words.

Comment: Sorry, I just want a function that turns the date into a pure Int. Like any other Int that can be added to, subtracted to etc!

Comment: @Ed George: A function that turns a pure `UTCTime` value into a pure `Int` is simple. A pure function that returns the present time in any form, using the result of `getCurrentTime`, is not merely impossible but a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Right, I understand that a little better but can you give an example of a function converting an `UTCTime` to an `Int`?

Comment: Ed George: Please look again at my posted code example. Particularly the last line, `print (f . date $ utcTime)` takes `utcTime :: UTCTime` and turns it to an `Int` and then prints it. As I've already told you, the function you're looking for is `f . date :: UTCTime -> Integer`.

Comment: I used this code: `date = fmap (toGregorian . localDay . zonedTimeToLocalTime) getZonedTime` along side this: 
`seed :: Int`
`seed = fromIntegral . f $ unsafePerformIO date` I am very aware that this is not good practice but as I mentioned previously in a comment on @Don's answer, the program is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to return values from a monadic context?

If you have a function of type:

```
 date :: IO Integer
 date = getCurrentTime >>= return . toModifiedJulianDay . utctDay
```

you can use it from any other function in the `IO` monad. Like so:

```
 main = do
     n <- date
     print n
```

where `n` will have type `Integer`. To (unsafely) convert `Integer` to `Int`, use `fromIntegral`

To actually convert the `IO Integer` function to an `IO Int` function, map `fromIntegral`, like so:

```
 date :: IO Integer
 date = getCurrentTime >>= return . fromIntegral . toModifiedJulianDay . utctDay
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I require a function to return an Int instead of using a main method just to print an Integer.
I came up with this shoddy code thinking it will work:
`method = do fromIntegral x`
     `where x = date'`
Maybe I have got the wrong end of the stick here?!

Comment: @Ed George: You can't write a (safe) function that does `IO a -> a`, but you can use Don's method above `do n <- date; foo n; ...` to pass your integer value to another function.  You can enter the IO monad any time you like, but you can never leave :)

Comment: Eventually I used the `date` function you defined alongside unsafePerformIO after realizing it was not the end of the world if i used it once!

Comment: @Ed George: That is an extremely misguided and unnecessary use of `unsafePerformIO` and is very likely to work incorrectly if used in any nontrivial program. If you're seriously attempting to learn Haskell I strongly encourage you to reconsider, because doing it that way probably indicates some fundamental misunderstandings of how things work.

Comment: I understand this but the program IS trivial. However after further questioning which functions would help more, I have now reverted to the functions used by Tarrasch below